# Maven dependency plugin producing a report without executing test-compile phase

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

How can I generate a report for example by goal: 
    dependency:analyze-report
but without executing test-compile phase?
Goal 
    dependency:analyze-only
does the thing without executing test-compile phase but does not create the report.

Comment: Just have `-DskipTests`?

Comment: [`-Dmaven.test.skip=true` also skips compiling the tests.](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html)